# Calling on parent class when child class is in another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to have a child class reside in another module. Currently it is more convenient for me to store the parent and child classes in different modules due to their size. I need the super method, since I want to inherit not just all the functions, but the variables in self as well. My current solution is as follows:

Parent Module (parent.py):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Child Module(child.py):

```
from parent import A

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

B()
```

When I run the child module I get the following error.

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I understand that this is due to the module reloading and thus causing data to be lost, however I am not sure if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

First, on your code:

- It's not necessary to always call the parent constructor, in particular calling `object`'s constructor as you do in `parent.A` is not needed
- In Python 3, you can use the much simpler `super().__init__` form for the call for single-inheritance
- The import should usually be relative: `from .parent import A`

Now, to your actual problem:

When you reload `parent` in this case, you essentially generate a new class object for `A` that is not identical to the one that your compiled `B` knows of. You can check this by comparing `id(B.__base__)` to `id(A)` after the reload. This is not a problem for the `super()` form, as that doesn't use the name `A` explicitly (which points to the new class) but instead uses the actual base class. So it will construct fine, but with the "old" `A` implementation.

P.S.:
It is essential that your question includes information on what you are actually trying to do, in this case reloading a module, which is not a "standard" operation in Python (that's why it's so cumbersome to do).